# Is it a bug to omit an Accept */* header in an HTTP/1.0 Request for a REST API

Tags: python, rest, http, curl, http-headers

I'm trying to determine whether it is a bug that Python's [*urllib.urlopen()*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlopen) function omits an HTTP Accept header when making simple REST API requests.

The [Facebook Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api) seems to notice whether the header is present or not:

```
GET /zuck HTTP/1.0
Host: graph.facebook.com
Accept: */*
```

Without the accept header, the returned *content-type* of `application/json; charset=UTF-8` becomes `text/javascript; charset=UTF-8`.  That may be a bug in Facebook's REST API or it may be a legitimate response to a missing accept header.

I notice the command-line tools like [*curl*](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) use `Accept: */*` by default:

```
$ curl -v https://graph.facebook.com/zuck
> GET /zuck HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
> Host: graph.facebook.com
> Accept: */*
```

Likewise, the [Python requests package](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) also uses `Accept: */*` as a default:

```
def default_headers():
    return CaseInsensitiveDict({
        'User-Agent': default_user_agent(),
        'Accept-Encoding': ', '.join(('gzip', 'deflate')),
        'Accept': '*/*',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    })
```

I presume that *curl* and *requests* add the default for a reason, but I'm not sure what that reason is.

[RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) for HTTP/1.1 says that  `*/* indicates all media types` and that `if no Accept header field is present, then it is assumed that the client accepts all media types`.  This would seem to indicate that `Accept: */*` is optional and its omission would have no effect.  That said, Python is using HTTP/1.0 and the RFCs are silent about the effect of omitting the header.

I would like to determine whether the best practice is to include `Accept: */*` as *curl* and *requests* do or whether it is okay to omit is as Python's *urllib.urlopen()* does.

The question is important because I'm in a position to [fix *urllib.urlopen()*](http://bugs.python.org/issue22450) if it is determined to be buggy or if it is problematic for use with REST APIs as commonly implemented using HTTP/1.0:

```
>>> import httplib
>>> httplib.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1
>>> import urllib
>>> u = urllib.urlopen('https://graph.facebook.com/zuck')
send: 'GET /zuck HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: graph.facebook.com\r\nUser-Agent: Python-urllib/1.17\r\n\r\n'
```

The related questions on StackOverflow aren't helpful for this question.  [What does 'Accept: */*' mean under Client section of Request Headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14772634) asks what `*/*` means (we already know that it means all media types) and [Send a curl request with no Accept header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18183467) asks how to omit the accept header in a *curl* request.  My question focuses on whether you should include `*/*` and whether it is a bug to omit it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading-up about proxy servers (like NGinx and Varnish) helped me figure out what is going on.

While the presence of an `Accept: */*` header shouldn't make a difference to a server, it can and likely will make a difference to a proxy server when the response includes a [`Vary: Accept`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.1.4) header.  In particular, the proxy server is allowed to cache different results for different or omitted *Accept* headers.

Facebook has updated (and closed-off) its API since this question was asked, but at the time, here is the scenario that caused the observed effects. [For backwards compatibility reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189850/what-is-the-javascript-mime-type-for-the-type-attribute-of-a-script-tag), Facebook was using content negotiation and responding with `text/javascript; charset=UTF-8` when getting the request that either omitted the `Accept` header or had a browser-like `Accept: text/html;text/*;*/*`.  However, when it received `Accept: */*`, it returned the more modern `application/json; charset=UTF-8`.  When a proxy server receives a request without an accept header, it can give either one of the cached responses; however, when it gets `Accept: */*`, it always gives the last response.

So here is **why you should include the `Accept: */*` header**:  If you do, then a caching proxy will alway return the same content type.  If omit the header, the response can vary depending on the results of the last user's content negotiation.  REST API clients tend to rely on always getting the same content type back every time.

Answer (score 15):

the RFC states

> The Accept request-header field can be used to specify certain media types which are acceptable for the response.

This means that the header is optional because it says `can be used`.

as you pointed out ther RFC also says:

> If no Accept header field is present, then it is assumed that the client accepts all media types.

This means that omitting the header SHOULD be equivalently interpreted by the server as sending `Accept: */*` in the sense that the client `acceptes all media types` in both cases.

It is interesting that the facebook response differs in both cases but I guess it is their failure of interpreting the protocol correctly. Though on the other side both responses are obviously correct responses to the request (Which I find a funny twist).

I have some general thoughts on this issue (which might also [contribute to the bugfix discussion](http://bugs.python.org/issue22450)):

1. Following [Postel Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle) `Be conservative in what you do, be liberal in what you accept from others (often reworded as "Be conservative in what you send, be liberal in what you accept").` you could decide to be more precise and explicitly add `Accept: */*`. You would be more precise helping the server that he might have misinterpreted the protocol (like facebook probably did) that a missing header would be equivalent to `Accept: */*`
2. Just adding header fields like `Accept: */*` which could be omitted increases network traffic by 11 Byte for every single request which might lead to performance issues. Having `Accept: */*` be default in the request might make it hard for developers to get it out of the header in order to save to 11 Byte.
3. There is a difference between a specification (or a **standard**) and a **de facto standard**. Obviously omitting the header field is perfect according to the specification on the other hand a lot of libraries seem to include this and services like the facebook API behave differently this can be seen as **a de facto standard** being created and you could jump into the loop and be part of creating it.

When speaking HTTP/1.1: Even though (1) und (3) speak for [fixing the urllib](http://bugs.python.org/issue22450) I would probably [follow the specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) and the performance argument (2) and omit the header. As stated above the response of facebook in both cases is correct since they are allowed to set the media type to whatever they like. (even though this behaviour seems unintended, weird, and by mistake)

When speaking HTTP/1.0: I would send the accept header since you said it is not specified in the HTTP/1.0 RFC and then I think Postel's law becomes more important. On the other side the Accept header is just optional in [http 1.0](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945#appendix-D.2.1). `The Accept request-header field can be used to indicate a list of media ranges which are acceptable as a response to the request` Why would you set an optional header by default?

Comment: Bear in mind,"de facto" standards are great when there are no standards ruling. If there is a standard, there is no such a thing as a "de facto" standard, as anything not conforming with the standard is just a violation (an things conforming are just standard). This problem domain we are talking has a ruling standard. Let's just conform to it.

Comment: IMO in an RFC, _"can"_ should not automatically be interpreted to _"optional"_, as you are implying. There are key words like _"MAY/MUST"_ for that. So I don't believe your first interpretation is a valid one, though the second quote _does_ backs the optional case. This comment is not to say that that this answer is wrong. Based on the evidence provided, it seems it _is_ optional. All I'm saying is that you should be careful how you interpret _"can"_. That first quote alone, without more context, is ambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

1. If a service reacts differently for `Accept: */*` and absent `Accept`, it is buggy (and you should send a bug report).
2. Furthermore, having a `charset` parameter on `application/json` is a bug as well; this is a media type that doesn’t have a `charset` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

[RFC 7231](http://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc7231) obsoletes [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616).

> The asterisk "*" character is used to group media types into ranges, with `"*/*"` indicating **all** media types and `"type/*"` indicating all subtypes of that type.
> ...

> A request without any Accept header field implies that the user agent will accept **any** media type in response.

> Source: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.3.2

From [RFC 7231](http://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc7231), *any* can be interpreted as most obsolete or most compatible and *all* can be interpreted as most recent media type if we consider [graph.facebook.com](https://graph.facebook.com)'s response and the list of `javascript/json` MIME media types; `text/javascript`, `text/ecmascript`, `application/javascript`, `application/ecmascript` and `application/json`.

It seems that the server considers user agents that omit an HTTP Accept header less capable and obsolete and from pre-json era. That may be the reason that it sends obsolete MIME media type [text/javascript](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/text/javascript) which is obsoleted by [application/javascript](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/javascript).

> That said, Python is using HTTP/1.0 and the RFCs are silent about the effect of omitting the header.
> @raymond-hettinger

It doesn't matter whether the request is HTTP/1.0 or HTTP/1.1, modern servers always respond with HTTP/1.1. So to be considered up-to-date by servers, user agents should include `Accept` header in requests. And also *Accept headers* participate in content negotiation.

Regarding `charset` in `application/json; charset=UTF-8`,

> JSON text SHALL be encoded in UTF-8, UTF-16, or UTF-32.  The default encoding is UTF-8.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#section-8.1

So it doesn't seem like an error.

Comment: This is a thoughtful and interesting answer; however, I don't see any part of the RFC that supports the interpretation that "**any** can be interpreted as most obsolete or most compatible and **all** can be interpreted as most recent media type".  Do you have a specific link to anything that supports that interpretation?  Even a link to some public REST server code that behaves that way would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

As you pointed out, RFC 2616 already states what is the expected behavior of a service in the absence of an `Accept` header (That it is equivalent to sending `Accept: */*`). From the specification we can infer

1. That not sending and `Accept` header is perfectly legal for an HTTP client.
2. That when this happens, the client intention is to accept any data representation and that the content negotiation on the service side decides which one to use.

So in your sample, neither your PHP client nor the service you are invoking are misbehaving. I guess there is nothing to fix there.