# How handle correctly HTTP Accept header when is either empty or null?

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, http, http-headers, spring-rest

I am working with `Spring Framework` about `Rest`.

I have the scenario about testing when the `request` is a `GET` and `Accept` is either `empty` or `null`.

It is closely related with:

- [@GetMapping is called even when Accept is defined how null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054312/getmapping-is-called-even-when-accept-is-defined-how-null)

I have read the following:

- [How to interpret empty HTTP Accept header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12130910/how-to-interpret-empty-http-accept-header)
- [What does 'Accept: */*' mean under Client section of Request Headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14772634/what-does-accept-mean-under-client-section-of-request-headers)

Seems the following options how solutions are valid:

1. `400 Bad Request`
2. `406 Not Acceptable`
3. Consider the `empty` or `null` value of `Accept` how `*/*` instead

Three options, that's the reason of this post.

Between the two first, I consider more appropriate `406 Not Acceptable`, it because it is *specific* or *tight* for `Accept`. I mean what media type represents `empty` or `null`? it is not a known media type such as `xml` or `json`

The third option seems illogic, according with the following points (*according my own points of view, perhaps I am wrong or missing something*):

The **server** has a handler method for `GET` that returns either `XML` or `json`, such as:

```
@GetMapping(path="/{id}",
            produces={MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE})
public @ResponseBody Persona findOneById(@PathVariable String id){
    return personaService.findOneById(id);
}
```

The **client** *should have clear from the beginning* that it would do the `request` and handle the `response` either `XML` or `json`, according the `Accept` sent through the `request`.

Thus, for any reason if the `request` sent has the `Accept` how `empty` (lets assume *wrong coding*), It is the third point (`*/*`) that I can't understand: "let the server return any media type"; even with that, lets assume the server returns `XML` and the client just can handle `JSON` instead, but of course that `Accept` how `Json` wasn't specified from the beginning. So the client once received the `response` should receive an exception, *but observe that the server did the work unnecessarily*

Thus: How handle correctly HTTP Accept header when empty or null?

Comment: In my experience, user agents (browsers, curl, etc.) being operated on behalf of a human include specific and valid values for the accept header.  Are you operating your server for humans or for computers (bots, scrapers, spiders, or legitimate API/Rest traffic from other servers)?  That should guide your response, weighted by whether you care about the cost and burden on your infrastructure from non-human traffic.

Comment: Consider the scenario where a remote service is calling my service through rest and that app does not include (bug) the `Accept` header.

Comment: I'm also facing same issue.any solution for that ?